# Using valueForKeyPath on an NSArray, how to count a BOOL property if property is set to YES

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSArray called allQuestions with objects that have a BOOL property called isCorrect

I tried

```
int res = [self.allQuestions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.isCorrect"];
```

but this always gives me a bogus number. I though YES would count as 1, and NO as 0. What am I missing here. Is there no guarantee of the values? If no, what's the best way do achieve this simple thing without iterating over the array?

Edit: just to be precise: I'm interested in the count (number) of elements that evaluate to YES.

Comment: That line should cause at least a compiler warning.

Comment: solved, the @sum seems to work, but returns NSNumber. In hindsight: obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int res = [[self.allQuestions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.isCorrect"] intValue];
```

valueForKeyPath returns NSNumber's object. You need convert it in to primitive type int or use pointer at NSNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the booleans in NSNumber when adding to an array:

```
BOOL b = YES;

[self.allQuestions addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:b]];
```

And retrieve in the same way:

```
 BOOL b = [[self.allQuestions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.isCorrect"] boolValue];
```

Comment: I'm stating in the title of the question: "how to count", i.e. I'd like to know a number, say 55 [questions are correct]

Comment: You edited the question after I edited the answer. Just use a for loop to parse all array items and any time you get the bool YES (with the code I wrote above) make an integer +1. It is pretty straightforward I think.

Comment: that's an obvious way of doing it, I agree, but I'm curious why my proposal doesn't work, it clearly does invoke all isCorrect properties, because I can see it when it does it, but then what? sums up the pointers? and there seems to be little to no documentation about how key paths work in general and what they offer... I used a simple example here, but had bigger things in mind; I like things like LINQ, I thought I could use key paths for basic stuff to keep the code more concise, but alas...

Comment: Because res is an Int and Bool values should be saved as NSNumber inside NSArrays.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    NSNumber * res = [self.allQuestions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.isCorrect"];
```

It returns an NSNumber, of course...